# hidden_field_tag value doesn't pass to the right params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I want `key_type` to pass in the `category_item_value` params hash on the form submit but it passes outside the hash.

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"H0p7vNzcl0r0KNPWTHOGgaem0ngpsjIq5DmXZ8A7woZOztECkC9lv5cBH0CloH4ivEL0VtU5uDMPZTJQZQDjOQ==", "category_item_value"=>{"key"=>"this-Is-AttRibute-Page", "value"=>"okkkkkkkk"}, "key_type"=>"", "commit"=>"Submit",...
```

Here is the form

```
 <%= form_for([@category_item, @category_item_value], url: create_category_item_value_path, method: :post) do |f|  %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

   <%= f.label :attribute, "Pick a key to add an attribute to." %> 
   <%= f.select :key, options_for_select(@key_names) %>

   <%= hidden_field_tag :key_type, 2 %>

   <%= f.label :value %> 
   <%= f.text_field :value %>

   <%= f.submit "Submit" %>

 <% end %>
```

I need the hidden field to pass inside the `category_item_value` hash. Why isn't it happening?

Also I know hidden fields are unsafe, users can change the `key_type` on other forms easily, so its not a problem if they try and be mr. hackety hack and change it on this one. Its just hidden for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

There were 2 problems.

1. `hidden_field_tag` was supposed to be `f.hidden_field`. This adds it to the right hash but throws an error.
2. to fix the error I replaced `:key_type, 2` with `:key_type, :value => 2`

Comment: Super. I was going to check the docs for you, but was en route to my computer. Glad you got it.

Comment: Yea your answer confirmed that my suspicions were right on the 'f' being there so I googled the errors and figured it out from there. Thanks